# R: Limit each element up to 5

Tags: r

If I have a data frame like this:

```
x
9
9
9
9
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
3
9
2
2
2
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
4
4
```

How do I limit each element up to 5 so that it looks like this?

```
x
9
9
9
9
7
7
7
7
7
3
9
2
2
2
5
5
5
5
5
4
4
```

Comment: If your vector is `[1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]`, the result should be `[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]` or `[1 1 1 1 1 2 2]`? I.e. the groups are `[a a a a a a b b c]` or `[a a a a a a b b a]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reminded me of a question I answered a day or two ago that asked for an index sequence within groups. Just had to add a logical test to that answer:

```
> df[ ave(df$x, df$x, FUN=seq_along) <= 5, ,drop=FALSE]
   x
1  9
2  9
3  9
4  9
5  7
6  7
7  7
8  7
9  7
12 3
13 9
14 2
15 2
16 2
17 5
18 5
19 5
20 5
21 5
24 4
25 4
```

If you leave off the drop=FALSE you get a vector rather than a dataframe.

Comment: `ave` was the first thing I tried, but I missed the simple `<= 5` trick.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 9, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5, 4, 4))
rep.int(unique(df$x), times = tapply(df$x, df$x, FUN = function(x) min(5, length(x)))[rank(unique(df$x))])
#  [1] 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran some benchmarks on all the solutions out of curiosity, following @Robert's comment under @beginneR's answer. I benchmarked on 50 million rows with a total of 10,000 unique values and here's the result:

#### Benchmarks timings with system.time()

```
#    function        pkg       user time (in sec)
# -----------------------------------------------
# 1:       f1       base      akrun          37.9
# 2:       f2      dplyr   beginneR           8.7
# 3:       f4       base     Robert          24.1
# 4:       f5       base   beginneR           NA*
# 5:       f6       base   beginneR           NA*
# 6:       f7       base     Robert           NA*
# 7:       f8       base BondedDust          22.2
# -------------------------------------------------
# 8:       f3 data.table       Arun           1.5 #
# -------------------------------------------------   
* - stopped after 2 minutes.
```

`data.table` solution is ~6x faster than the fastest solution **here** (meaning on this data set with 50 million rows, which is approximately 190MB - which is not a large data set at all!).

#### Generate data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(45L)
K = 1e4L
N = 5e7L
df <- data.frame(x=sample(K, N, TRUE))
```

#### Here are the functions:

```
f1 <- function() {
    inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$x), 
            lengths <- ifelse(lengths >5, 5, lengths)))
}

## updated with beginneR's version
f2 <- function() {
    df %>% 
    group_by(x) %>%
    filter(row_number() <= 5)
}

f4 <- function() {
    rep.int(unique(df$x), times = tapply(df$x, df$x, 
       FUN = function(x) min(5, length(x)))[rank(unique(df$x))])
}

f5 <- function() {
    unlist(sapply(unique(df$x), function(y) rep(y, min(5, sum(df$x == y)))))
}

f6 <- function() {
    rl <- rle(df$x)
    unlist(sapply(seq_along(rl[[1]]), function(y) 
              rep(rl[[2]][y],  min(5, rl[[1]][y]))))
}

f7 <- function() {
    df[-as.integer(row.names(Reduce(function(df, i) 
             df[duplicated(df), ,drop = F], 1:5, df))), ]
}

f8 <- function() {
    df[ ave(df$x, df$x, FUN=seq_along) <= 5,]
}

f3 <- function() {
    setDT(df)$x[df[, .I[seq_len(min(.N, 5L))], by=x][order(V1)]$V1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for consecutive elements, you could also use:

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$x), lengths <- ifelse(lengths >5, 5, lengths)))
# [1] 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 9 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4
```

If it is not:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
group_by(x) %>%
mutate(n=row_number()) %>% 
filter(n<=5) %>% select(-n)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df1)[,n:=1:.N, by=x][,n<=5]
df2 <- df1[indx][,n:=NULL]
df2$x
#[1] 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 9 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4
```

Comment: Or: `setDT(df)$x[df[, .I[seq_len(min(.N, 5L))], by=x][order(V1)]$V1]`

Comment: `group_by(df, x) %>% filter(row_number() <= 5)` will be faster than your `dplyr` code.

Comment: @beginnerR. thanks ok.  It should be as it is not creating an additional variable and removing it.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
unlist(sapply(unique(df$x), function(y) rep(y, min(5, sum(df$x == y)))))
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4
```

But I prefer the answer by @BondedDust, which should also be a lot faster

It seems that my initial approach may be wrong, since due to the `unique(df$x)` one 9 later in that vector didn't occur. So here's another approach if the limit of 5 is applied to each sequence (not each unique element):

```
rl <- rle(df$x)
unlist(sapply(seq_along(rl[[1]]), function(y) rep(rl[[2]][y],  min(5, rl[[1]][y]))))
#[1] 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 9 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4     #  <- notice the 9 at position 11
```

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski, really?, I expected something totally different :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `duplicated`:

```
df[-as.integer(row.names(Reduce(function(df, i) df[duplicated(df), ,drop = F], 1:5, df))), ]
# [1] 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 3 9 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4
```